# Erro na instalação do Cassandra - DRIVER no python

Tags: python, windows, cassandra, anaconda

Olá, estou tentando criar um ambiente de desenvolvimento com python e Cassandra, porem estou tendo dificuldades para instalar o Conector no python, segue abaixo o ambiente que tenho atualmente o  erro que estou tendo de retorno.
Sistema Operacional: Windows 8.1
Python : Versão 3.6
Anaconda : Versão 3.x

Instalei o cassandra e esta funcionando, o Anaconda eu instalei pois preciso do Jupyter Notebook para fazer um trabalho, e neste trabalho preciso me conectar no banco de dados cassandra, para instalar o conector eu fiz o seguinte 
1 tentativa eu fui no python e dei o seguinte comando via Power Shell do windows
.\PIP INSTALL CASSANDRA-DRIVER

e estou tendo este retorno de erro

> Collecting cassandra-driver   Downloading
>   cassandra-driver-3.12.0.tar.gz (222kB)
>       100% |████████████████████████████████| 225kB 2.0MB/s Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9 in
>   c:\users\rodrigoaugusto\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-pa
>   ckages (from cassandra-driver) Installing collected packages:
>   cassandra-driver   Running setup.py install for cassandra-driver ...
>   error Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "c:\users\rodrigoaugusto\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\compat__init__.py",
>   lin e 73, in console_to_str
>       return s.decode(sys.**stdout**.encoding) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 9: invalid
>   continuation byte
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "c:\users\rodrigoaugusto\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py",
>   line 21 5, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)   File "c:\users\rodrigoaugusto\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py",
>   li ne 342, in run
>       prefix=options.prefix_path,   File "c:\users\rodrigoaugusto\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py",
>   line 78 4, in install
>       **kwargs   File "c:\users\rodrigoaugusto\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py",
>   lin e 878, in install
>       spinner=spinner,   File "c:\users\rodrigoaugusto\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils__init__.py",
>   line  676, in call_subprocess
>       line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())   File "c:\users\rodrigoaugusto\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\compat__init__.py",
>   lin e 75, in console_to_str
>       return s.decode('utf_8') UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 9: invalid continuation byte

2 Tentativa foi por dentro do Conda , eu dei o comando para instalar e deu o mesmo erro, não sei o que pode estar acontecendo e nao tenho capacidade técnica para identificar que erro e este, gostaria de uma ajuda para tentar resolver este problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse é um erro com codificação - infelizmente, 25 anos depois do mundo ter padronizado uma codificação de acentos que aceita caractéres do mundo inteiro - o utf-8, a microsoft com o windows continua usando codifciações parciais que são específicas para cada língua. No caso do windows (o seu tem uns 4 anos de idade, mas mesmo no windows 10 não mudaram isso).

O seu traceback mostra onde acontece o erro, um dos componentes da instalação lê a saída de um sub-processo para a saída padrão e tenta tratar isso como texto - e o subprocesso da saída padrão imprime um caractere acentuado -- que usa a codificação "latin1" do Windows, mas é inválido na codificação "utf-8" assumida pelo PIP.

```
"...pip\utils__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline()) "
```

Isso é um bug do PIP. O catactere que ele mostra que e utf-8 inválido, de código `\xf3` corresponde a o caractpere `ó` em latim-1.

Uma forma de contornar o erro é configurar a linguagem do seu sistema para inglês - mesmo que seja temporariamente - faça isso, e rode a instalação do driver do cassandra em inglês.

Se tiver problemas ao usar o driver depois, o negócio é manter tudo em inglês mesmo.

Teoricamente você não precisa mudar a língua do Windows inteiro para fazer isso - basta configurar a variável de ambiente `LANG` no PowerShell onde for rodar o PIP. Mas o windows não é lá conhecido por ser consistente com essas coisas.  De qualquer forma, tente digitar o comando `$env:LANG=C` no terminal do powershell antes de tentar o `pip install` como você fez acima.

(**em tempo**: por que então o erro não acontece com todos os pacotes de Python? Bom - a maioria dos pacotes de Python não traduz as suas mensagens, e um número ainda menor traduz as mensagens impressas durante a instalação - Acontece que esse driver do cassandra está imprimindo as mensagens traduzidas, como indicado pela presença dessa letra `ó` que causou o erro)

Comment: Nota pra quem estive rno windows em português: se conseguirem reproduzir o erro, vale a pena abrir uma issue no github do PIP: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues - uma ou duas frases de contexto e o traceback acima devem ser suficientes.

Comment: Obrigado deu certo aqui.

Comment: Já corrigiram no código de desenvolvimento do PIP - na versão 10 o problema deve estar solucionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/269710/500