# Erro UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte ao instalar rpy2 com pip

Tags: python-3.x, windows

Estou tentando instalar o rpy2 que é um pacote para executar linguagem R no python, mas dá o erro:

```
$ pip install rpy2

< Using cached rpy2-2.9.2.tar.gz
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line
 73, in console_to_str
    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc6 in position 6: invalid
continuation byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215
, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", lin
e 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in b
uild
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380
, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 634
, in _prepare_file
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 129
, in prep_for_dist
    self.req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line
 439, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line
676, in call_subprocess
    line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line
 75, in console_to_str
    return s.decode('utf_8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc6 in position 6: invalid
continuation byte >
```

Versões:
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit
pip 9.0.1

Comment: Qual versão do pip e python está sendo usada? Verifique com `pip --version`

Comment: @rodorgas editei a pergunta e coloquei as versões do python, anaconda e pip.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Erro na instalação do Cassandra - DRIVER no python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/265862/erro-na-instala%c3%a7%c3%a3o-do-cassandra-driver-no-python)

Comment: apesar de ser outro pacote, é o mesmo problema que está na pergunta que marquei como duplicada. Na resposta lá está descrita uma forma de fazer funcionar sem precisar do upgrade do pip.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que se trata [de um erro de codificação do pip 9.0.1](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/4486), que já foi corrigido e estará disponível no pip 10.

Para não ter que aguardar o pip 10, você pode instalar a versão de desenvolvimento com:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/pypa/pip.git
```

Pelo que eu vi afeta usuários de Windows com caracteres especiais no caminho do projeto, então uma gambiarra possível é alterar a pasta do seu projeto para um caminho sem caracteres especiais.

Outra gambiarra, que pode funcionar na versão estável do pip, seria rodar o seguinte comando antes de instalar um pacote:

```
chcp 65001
```

Link do pull request no GitHub corrigindo o problema: https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/4486

Comment: Digitei o pip install +link do github,mas dá o erro: nt-type: text/html; charset=utf-8); cannot detect archive format
Cannot determine archive format of C:\Users\USUARIO\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-c6bt1
4ed-build. Vou apagar a instalação do anaconda que instalei para todos usuários e vou reinstalar apenas para meu usuário.

Comment: @AndréNascimento Desculpe, o comando para instalação está errado. O correto é `pip install git+https://github.com/pypa/pip.git` ao invés de `pip install https://github.com/pypa/pip`. Eu sempre erro isso :p